# Add-PnPListItem with a look up value

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to add items to a list via IMport-CSV i can import all columns expect a look up column called GroupDept I get the follow error `add-PnPListItem : Input string was not in a correct format.` If i delete this column input it will allow me to add the item.

```
#Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
#Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

$SiteURL = "SITEURL"
$ListName =":ist"
$CSVFile = "C:\Imports.csv"

Connect-PnPOnline -useweblogin -Url $SiteURL

#Get the CSV file contents

$CSVData = Import-CsV -Path $CSVFile
 
#Iterate through each Row in the CSV and import data to SharePoint Online List

ForEach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
# add note in window stating adding user

    Write-Host "Adding Item $($Row.'Asset Number')" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    #Add List Items - Map with Internal Names of the Fields!
    $inputup = $($Row.'UP')
    $inputSubmitter = $($Row.'Submitter')
   $inputGroupDept = $($Row.'GroupDebt')
    $UnloadDrive = $($Row.'ContentDate')
    $inputTcktNum = $($Row.'TicketNbr')

    $listvalues = @{
    "Title" = $inputupns; 
    "Submitter" = $inputSubmitter;
    "UnloadDate" = $UnloadDrive;
    "TicketNbr" =  $inputTcktNum;
    "GroupDept" = "$inputGroupDept";
   
    };
 Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -ContentType Item   -Values   $listvalues


  write-host "Item Added" `n
}
Write-Host "ALL Items Complete "
```

Comment: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPListItem.html#examples

Comment: For lookup-columns - use the lookup list item-ID instead of the actual text-based value.

Comment: thank you can you give me an example if the value i am trying to find is Sports|Baseball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add-PnPListItem` or `Set-PnPListItem` expect a lookup ID, not a lookup Value.

**Example. This will not work**

```
Add-PnPListitem List $ListName  -Values @{Title=""; GroupDebt="Debt Value"}
```

**Example. This will work**

```
Add-PnPListitem List $ListName  -Values @{Title=""; GroupDebt="612"}
```

So, what you can do is this:
Before adding a lookup value as you do, first, in the lookup list find an item with the value you are looking for. Then, use this ID to assign the value

```
$lookupListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Lookup List Title"
$lookupItem = $lookupListItems | Where-Object {$_["Title"] -eq "Sports|Baseball "}

if ($lookupItem){
  Add-PnPListitem List $ListName  -Values @{Title=""; GroupDebt=$lookupItem["ID"]}
}else{
  Write-Host Alas! No lookup item exists with this value
}
```

[More info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/566729/update-sharepoint-lookup-field-external-data-pnp-p.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! i was able to make that work!